# How to write the query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query from joining two tables, and the result shows below:

```
ID   Provider  Vendor   Location  Funding
-----------------------------------------
1     AAAA     ABC       Dallas   NSF
2     AAAA     ABC       Houston  NIH
3     CCCC     TEST      NYC      NASA
4     FFFF     Exam      Boston   FDA
5     FFFF     Appl      Miami     FDA
6     EEEE     Google    San Jose  FDA
```

My question, I want to generate only ID that have both Funding. For example:

output:

```
ID   Provider  Vendor   Location  Funding
-----------------------------------------

1     AAAA     ABC       Dallas   NSF
2     AAAA     ABC       Houston  NIH
```

The data column is few thousand records, thus I'm looking for a best way to go in SQL.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your requirements are rather ambiguous. Please provide a larger data sample that covers more test cases.

Comment: You might also want to include the query you're currently using - we don't know your data, and guesswork is not an exact science. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the original rows, you can do this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(distinct funding) over (partition by provider) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

If you just want the providers, use aggregation:

```
select provider
from t
where funding in ('NSF', 'NIH')
group by provider
having count(distinct funding) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

Assumption: by ID you refer to Provider

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
                  (
             ID INT, Provider VARCHAR(10), Vendor VARCHAR(10), Location VARCHAR(10), Funding VARCHAR(10)
                  );

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
       (1, 'AAAA', 'ABC', 'Dallas', 'NSF'
       ),
       (2, 'AAAA', 'ABC', 'Houston', 'NIH'
       ),
       (3, 'CCCC', 'TEST', 'NYC', 'NASA'
       ),
       (4, 'FFFF', 'Exam', 'Boston', 'FDA'
       ),
       (5, 'FFFF', 'Appl', 'Miami', 'FDA'
       ),
       (6, 'EEEE', 'Google', 'San Jose', 'FDA'
       );
```

Query if you just want ID's that either have NIH or NSF:

```
SELECT ID, Provider, Vendor, Location, Funding
FROM #temp
WHERE Funding IN
                 ('NSF', 'NIH'
                 );
```

Result Query1:

[image]

Query if you want ID's that have both NIH and NSF:

```
;WITH CTE
     AS
        (SELECT DISTINCT
                Provider, Funding, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                                                    (PARTITION BY Provider ORDER BY Funding
                                                    ) AS rn
         FROM #temp
         WHERE Funding IN
                          ('NSF', 'NIH'
                          )
        )
     SELECT *
     FROM #temp
     WHERE Provider IN
                      (
                       SELECT DISTINCT
                              Provider
                       FROM CTE
                       WHERE rn = 2
                      );
```

Result Query2:

[image]